# Black Diamond With White Question Mark

Tags: jquery, ajax, utf-8

I'm using this code:

```
$("#myDiv").load("getTweet.php?tweet_id="+tweet_id+"&yes="+yes+"&no="+no);
```

to call for a tweet, which is then delivered, but in the place of single quotation marks, I get black diamonds with a white question mark.

I have tried using

```
htmlspecialchars($tweet,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8")` and `mb_convert_encoding($tweet, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

before sending the tweet, but that didn't do anything. And besides, when I just go to "getTweet.php", the quotes are display just fine. But when I try to load them through ajax, they somehow get converted into something that can't be displayed.

Another thing that seems weird to me is that sometimes the quotes are displayed fine, but other times, they show up as black boxes.

I've also tried

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

What's weird is sometimes they work, and sometimes they don't. Also, sometimes one works, and the other doesn't.

Sometimes I just have to have neither of them on, and it is displayed correctly.

I should also mention, I got all of my data from twitter, and at the top of their site, they have `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which I have too.

So if anyone could shed some light on this, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting back one of the many quotation marks that are supported in Unicode. Some operating systems convert them as you type (windows can be guilty). There a lot of complexity in this, but for reference the Wikipedia page gives some reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Particularly this:

> "Curved and straight quotes are also sometimes referred to as smart quotes (“…”) and dumb quotes ("…") respectively; these names are in reference to the name of a function found in several word processors that automatically converts straight quotes typed by the user into curved quotes. This function, known as "educating quotes", was developed for systems that lack separate open- and close-quote keyboard keys."

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getTweet.php?tweet_id="+tweet_id+"&yes="+yes+"&no="+no,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#myDiv").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: This did nothing at all